# How do I djvubind on ls and grep result?

Tags: grep, ls

How do I djvubind only files that are in `ls | grep -P "page\\d\\d\\d.tif"`?

Answer (score 2):

*Hurried readers can skip down to **Putting Everything Together** and read just that section--but for users new to the topic I suggest starting from the beginning.*

### Basic Principles

Running `djvubind` so it only uses files named `pageNNN.tif` (where each **`N`** is some digit) is in one way significantly more complicated than you might be thinking, while in another way is a bit less complicated.

- **Passing the names of just the desired `.tif` files to the `djvubind` command will not work**, because [`djvubind` takes a *directory* as its argument](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/djvubind.1.html), and insists on trying to use all the files directly contained in that directory.

  One way to get around this is to build another directory of [hard links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) pointing to files in the directory you started with, running `djvubind` on *that* directory, then (optionally) removing it. I will present that method in this answer.

  <sup>Normally, for this sort of thing, [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) would be preferred to hard links. However, `djvubind` apparently skips over symbolic links automatically, refusing to process the files they point to. (There doesn't seem to be any option to change this behavior, but if someone knows of a way, I--or they--can edit this answer.)</sup>
- But it is less complicated in that you do not need to invoke [`ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/ls.1.html) or even [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/grep.1.html).

  <sup>Except for some rare situations where the only goal is to show a directory listing to the user, [it is generally best to avoid parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). And while `grep` certainly may be used for this purpose, your approach has the disadvantage of selecting some files with quite different names, like `rampage999.tiffany's.revenge.mp3`. (You could fix that by [passing `grep` the `-x` flag](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control), but really you don't need `grep` at all for this.)</sup>

### Selecting the Desired Files

There are two especially popular methods for selecting files that match a particular pattern:

1. [shell globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) and [a for loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs)
2. [the `find` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) (which [accepts similar globbing syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Shell-Pattern-Matching))

I'll use the first way in this guide, and show the commands for the second way at the end.

First, I suggest composing and trying out a command just to show the names of the files we want to operate on. This is to help avoid mistakes--you'll see if you're selecting the files correctly or not. To do this, you can run `printf '%s\n' filename` for each one. (For the real thing, you'll replace `printf '%s\n'` with a different command.)

```bsh
for x in page[0-9][0-9][0-9].tif; do printf '%s\n' "$x"; done
```

Note that the glob (`page[0-9][0-9][0-9].tif`) is *un*quoted, as the shell must expand it, then loop through the expanded list. (Testing will look [something like this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10726053/), though your output will be longer if you have many files. You should be able to see how only the correct files are selected.)

### Putting Everything Together

Now for the real thing. Make a directory to store the hard links:

```bsh
mkdir page-links
```

Populate the new directory with hard links to the desired files:

```bsh
for x in page[0-9][0-9][0-9].tif; do ln "$x" "page-links/$x"; done
```

Run `djvubind` on the newly populated `page-links` directory:

```bsh
djvubind page-links
```

Optionally, remove the directory of hard links:

```bsh
rm -r page-links
```

It will look [something like this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10726326/).

### If you prefer `find`...

To use `find` instead of shell globbing and a for loop:

- use `-mindepth 1` to prevent the containing directory from being considered as a possible match,
- use `-maxdepth 1` so that only files directly contained in the current directory (not those in its subdirectories) are matched, and
- *do* quote the pattern, as it must be passed unexpanded by the shell to the `find` command (which then performs the matching).

List the files:

```bsh
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name 'page[0-9][0-9][0-9].tif'
```

Without specifying any action, the default `-print` action is used, listing the files you have selected. Results will be preceded by `./`, but that won't cause any problems here.

After creating the target directory (`mkdir page-links`), populate it:

```bsh
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name 'page[0-9][0-9][0-9].tif' -exec ln {} page-links/{} \;
```

<sup>You don't have to quote `{}`, though some people like to do so because it clarifies (to humans) that it is not a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion), and perhaps it is necessary to do so when invoking `find` from some non-Bourne-style shells, if they use different brace expansion syntax. Note that, whether or not you quote it, `find` will behave the same--[*including* for files with spaces in their names](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8524066/). (`find` never sees the quotes, as they are [removed by the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal) before `find` runs. The misconception that quoting `{}` has something to do with the way `find`'s `-exec` action passes filenames to commands is why I don't quote it.)</sup>

After that, running `djvubind` (and optionally removing the `page-links` directory afterwards) will of course work exactly the same way.